# Silex, loading own classes

Tags: php, autoload, silex

I play around with Silex, PHP micro-framework. At the moment I try to load my own classes but I have no luck doing it. Maybe somebody could explain me a little how does loading in Silex works?

My project structure looks like this:

```
app/
vendor/
web/
tests/
bootstrap.php
composer.json
composer.lock
```

Let's say I want to load a class `Controller\User (namespace here)` from `/app/MainController.php`.

How can I do that? I've browsed some articles (loading via Composer or Symfony's UniversalClassLoader), followed some instructions, and still it does not work.

If someone could give me a hand with it please, I would appreciate it.

Comment: Have a look at the docs on http://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md, I use the autoload to load my own classes

Comment: I swear I did it before.. Well, I had to miss something. It's trivial. Still, thank you, gunnx.

Comment: Try again and if you are getting any specific errors, post them on here.

Comment: What I meant is that it worked this time :)

Comment: Hey Alku, I've got a project-example in Silex. Feel free to look into the code, it's working fine. Cheers.

https://github.com/medinadato/restbeer

Comment: Have a look at http://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md#autoloading autoloading session

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I assume you load your Silex classes in bootstrap.php like that:

```
// bootstrap.php
require_once __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';
```

If so replace this code with the following:

```
// bootstrap.php
$loader = require __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';
$loader->add(YOUR_NAMESPACE, DIRECTORY_OF_THE_NAMESPACE);
```

Example:

```
// bootstrap.php
$loader = require __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';
$loader->add('Tutorial', __DIR__.'/src');
```

You can add multiple namespaces if you like, just call the add method for every namespace.
In `src/` you would store your class files. For every namespace create a folder which contains your class files for this namespace. 
The file should have the same name as the class.

MyNamespace\MyClass => src/MyNamespace/MyClass.php
MyNamespace\SubNamespace\SubClass => src/MyNamespace/SubNamespace/SubClass.php

In every class file you have to set the associated namespace in the first line.

```
// src/Tutorial/DemoController.php
namespace Tutorial;
class DemoController{
// class definition goes here..
}
```

You have now access to your classes in every file which includes bootstrap.php.
In /app/MainController.php you can now access your own class like this:

```
// app/MainController.php
use Tutorial\DemoController;
$foo = new DemoController();
```

This solution worked for me. Hope it works for you.

Comment: Actually I read again the Composer documentation more thoroughly and I  managed to make it work (as I wrote in comments to my question).

I'm sure your post will help some other people with loading classes with Composer.

Comment: this solution is maybe fine for development purpose. But when it comes to deploy to production you not want any bootstrap to load classes by scanning the file system on each request. Thats why composer can manage that for you in the autoload configuration. Where that gets optimised to class map when it comes to production deployment.

Answer (score 3):

I was also looking for the same thing, since Silex documentation still has the registerNamespace function that was removed.

Found a really nice answer [here](http://alanhollis.com/silex-autoloading-namespaces-with-composer/)

In Short, all you have to do, is add a "psr-0" in "autoload" section in the **composer.json**

Example composer.json:

```json
{
    "require": {
        "silex/silex": "~1.3",
        "doctrine/dbal": "~2.2"
    },

    "autoload": {
        "psr-0": {
            "MyApp": "src/"
        }
    }
}
```

Make sure to update the Composer Autoloader ("composer install" or "composer update")

Comment: This solution is probably the best. The -o option of composer will optimise it even further to use internally the class map.

Answer (score 2):

As of October, 2014 the best way to autoload your own classes into silex, is using `PSR-4` (instead of `PSR-0`) autoloading through `Composer` using `composer.json` file in your application root:

```
{
    "require": {
        "silex/silex": "~2.0",
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {"Vendor\\Namespace\\": "path/to/src/"}
    }
}
```

After editing your `composer.json` you need to do a:

```
composer update
```

on your project root directory, using terminal.